# Facebook Linter showing og:type as webpage when it is defined as company

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I have a company web page that I've added a Facebook 'Like' button too. I have defined the namespace for FB and OG and added in all my Metatags - my code is below. URL is [www.akascia.com](http://www.akascia.com).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Akascia" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.akascia.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.akascia.com/images/akascia_fb_logo.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Executive search, purely done by Akascia" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="********" />
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="**********" />
<meta property="og:email" content="admin@akascia.com"/>
<meta property="og:phone_number" content="+44 2070 787 665"/>
```

However, when I run the site through the Facebook linter, I get the following results:

**Warnings that should be fixed**

```
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named fb:page_id.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:email.
Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:phone_number.
```

**Open Graph Object Properties**

```
fb:admins   Array of length 1
            ⍾ ********
og:url  http://www.akascia.com/
og:type  website
og:title  Akascia
og:image    
og:site_name  Executive search, purely done by Akascia
og:updated_time  1320835017
```

**Raw Open Graph Document Information**

```
Canonical URL  http://www.akascia.com/
Meta Tag  <meta property="og:title" content="Akascia" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="company" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.akascia.com" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.akascia.com/images/akascia_fb_logo.png" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Executive search, purely done by Akascia" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:admins" content="731575475" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:page_id" content="114216411121" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:email" content="admin&#64;akascia.com" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:phone_number" content="+44 2070 787 665" />
```

So it seems that it thinks the webpage should have the og:type:webpage, even though I'm declaring as a 'company' and in the raw data it's showing it's scraped it as 'company' too. Hence it's giving the warnings for the telephone numbers etc.

The 'Like' button seems to work but I'm not 100% sure it's right. So I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: I got the error when trying to use the fb linter: Error Scraping Page: Bad Response Code

Comment: I also got this error when I tried to validate the page: 500 Can't connect to www.akascia.com:80 (connect: timeout)

Comment: We're having the same exact problem... og:type is company, Facebook is treating it like og:type website.

Answer (score 4):

The current list of builtin object types is listed here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/objects/builtin/

Company isn't in the list. Website is the default that it's falling back to, and if you scroll down the page to where it has an example for a Website Object type, you can see it doesn't list support for all your properties, hence the Extraneous Property warnings.

You can create your own object type, though, that supports any properties you want. Create a Facebook Application, and go to the "Open Graph" section. You can create an action and an object type (such as, perhaps "like" a "company"), and then go to the "Open Graph/Dashboard" to add custom properties to your "company" object type. One type of custom property is a ContactInfo that would include your phone number and such; or you could just add a few string properties that are exactly what you need. You can then click "Get Code" to copy the new set of meta tags to use on your page.

This walkthrough probably describes the process better: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/customopengraph/walkthrough/

But really, after all that, if you're happy with how it is showing up on peoples' feed when they "Like" your page, then it is probably fine the way it is. You could add an og:description tag with any extra info you want in there, and just delete the extraneous tags.

Comment: I guess I was expecting to see a recommended path to take to replace og:type company with something that will be equally as popular/supported. We could roll our own namespace, etc., but I was under the impression that some search engines and social networks out there were actually using all of the related meta information specifically associated with og:type=company. And that there would be a recommended path forward to continue having these categories supported even if with a "third party," popular og:type?

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I hadn't checked this for ages and just came across my own question when searching for the answer again! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

old og:type like company, product ... are deprecated. They are not included in the current OpenGraph specification.

Very few og:type are still available (website, article, video....).

If you really want to use the og:type company, you will have to declare it in your own opengraph namespace.

CF : http://ogp.me/ , http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/objects/builtin/
(the last link was first added by Melinda Weathers)

Comment: A lot of other og properties are also deprecated (email...). See ogp.me for more information. In my opinion, there is a lack of communication about all of this.

Comment: A link or quote from the documentation would add trustworthiness to your answer.

Comment: Yeah and some indication as to what a person that previously had og:type company should do to reclassify themselves, especially since og:type company came with a lot of other og: meta data that made sense to know about a company.

Answer (score 1):

For the fb:admin tag, try putting in a personal profile's link.

i.e. your facebook page has a profile associated with it which is an admin to the page- the ID for the profile should work.